# All WordPress contact form failed to send any message

Tags: wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

All plugins of contact form shows me the same message when i try to fill up the form and press the "SEND" button, "There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later." i have checked all well known possibilities and try to implement all possible actions but still its showing me same error.

Some one please help me in this case.

That is the link of the form:
Visit https://design-signals.com/contact-us/

(try to change "TO" & "FROM" emails but still shows me same error)
(email is generated from CPanel and its on working state)

```
/*--THIS IS THE CODE OF THE FORM--*/

<label> Your Name (required)
[text* your-name] </label>

<label> Your Email (required)
[email* your-email] </label>

<label> Subject
[text your-subject] </label>

<label> Your Message
[textarea your-message] </label>

[submit "Send"]

/*--THIS IS THE MAIL SETTING TAB--*/

TO: admin@design-signals.com

FROM: Design Signals <wordpress@design-signals.com>

SUBJECT: Design Signals "[your-subject]"

ADDITIONAL HEADER: Reply-To: [your-email]

MESSAGE BODY:

From: [your-name] <[your-email]>

Subject: [your-subject]

Message Body: [your-message]

--This e-mail was sent from a contact form on Design Signals (https://design-signals.com)
```

Comment: Also i wanna add, different WordPress theme on a same CPanel with same contact form setting works completely fine.

Comment: If that's the case, try activating Twenty Nineteen theme and testing the contact form - if it works with another theme, you'll know what the issue is. The above code looks fine to me.

Comment: You really should be using an SMTP server for sending mail,  rather than relying on CPanel's internal server mailer. Is this the case?

Comment: Jamie_D i am using regular CPanel internal server mailer and Thunder Bird.